# static_cast and reinterpret_cast for std::aligned_storage

Tags: c++, alignment, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

could someone please explain the bit of code about casting in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage please?

can the following code

```
return *static_cast<const T*>(static_cast<const void*>(&data[pos]));
```

be replaced with

```
 return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[pos]);
```

?

Why here two casting are used?
Thanks a lot.

Hong

Comment: I suspect this is something that's required for proper portability / standard conformance because the result of `reinterpret_cast` isn't specified in the standard. In practice they probably do the same thing in all or almost all implementations.

Comment: The two are equivalent in C++11.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  I think that's an answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling: it would be if I was sure that it's correct (first that `reinterpret_cast` is under-specified for the job, and second that this is the reason that example code uses those two casts). It's a bit of a poor showing, if `std::aligned_storage` really does give you something that's two casts away from being usable.

Comment: I first used `reinterpret_cast` in that cppreference example but then changed to this `static_cast` chain with the comment 'avoid formal UB' after reading the Lounge discussion starting from http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10437436#10437436 and the TR1-age post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1082398/273767 .. but I may have been overly cautious. Feel free to change back if someone posts a convincing answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to the standard (§ 5.2.10 `reinterpret_cast`, section 7):

> A pointer to an object can be explicitly converted to a pointer to a diﬀerent object type. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is converted to the type “pointer to `cv T2`”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` **if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`.**
>
> Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to T2” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. **The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspeciﬁed.**

So, we could make the following conclusion:

1. `reinterpret_cast<*T>(ptr)` is eqiuvalent to `static_cast<*T>(static_cast<void*>(ptr))`
2. `static_cast<>(ptr)` is not always equal to `ptr`, but `reinterpret_cast<>(ptr)` is always equal to `ptr`
3. if there is no alignment issues, we can use `reinterpret_cast` safely