# reinterpret_cast vs. static_cast for writing bytes in standard-layout types?

Tags: c++, c++11, reinterpret-cast, visual-c++-2005, standard-layout

I need to write to individual bytes of some integer types. Should I used `reinterpret_cast`, or should I use `static_cast` via `void*`?

(a)

```
unsigned short v16;
char* p = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&v16));
p[1] = ... some char value
p[0] = ... some char value
```

or (b)

```
unsigned short v16;
char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v16);
p[1] = ... some char value
p[0] = ... some char value
```

According to [static_cast and reinterpret_cast for std::aligned_storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300142/static-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-for-stdaligned-storage) 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19636998/321013) both should be equivalent --

> -- if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types and the alignment
>   requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1

I'm leaning towards `reinterpret_cast` as that *is* essentially what I'm doing, isn't it?

Are there any other things to consider, specifically looking at Visual-C++ and VC8, the version we're currently compiling on? (x86 only atm.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case (converting object pointers), `reinterpret_cast` is identical to the two nested `static_cast` via `void*`

**5.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]**

> 7 An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer
>   of a diﬀerent type.72 When a prvalue v of object pointer type is
>   converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is
>   **`static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`**. Converting a prvalue of
>   type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are
>   object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no
>   stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value.

It is better to use `reinterpret_cast` to **signal your intent** here.

**UPDATE**: as mentioned in the comments, this was apparently added in C++11, although most C++98 compilers already supported it (see also [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573345/819272))

Comment: By the way, it is a novelty in C++11. C++98 seems to have no such clause.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy OK, that's good to know, but I think that the semantics were identical.

Comment: As far as I could make it out, there was only one thing you might *legally* do in C++98 with a `reinterpret_cast`-produced pointer, namely, to `reinterpret_cast` it back.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy I found another Q&A where they claim that most c++98 compilers already supported this, and it was made formally legal in c++11

Comment: I think `reinterpret_cast` has always been the most natural and common way to do the cast, and I was always puzzled that that wasn't reflected in the standard.

Comment: I'd use reinterpret_cast... but do watch out for byte-endianness on your platform.  p[0] might not be the lower 8 bits of your unsigned short.

Comment: @Andre - heh :-)  guess what the original code's purpose was

Comment: @MartinBa Look for helper functions on your platform.  Such as htons/ntohs/htonl/ntohl.  POSIX-compliant as I recall.

Comment: @TemplateRex - it's OK. I guess the `reinterpret_cast` mess doesn't get any clearer than this :-) accepted.

Comment: @MartinBa tnx, and `reinterpret_cast` is as verbose as it is for precisely that reason: otherwise it would be a hidden mess :-)